# Digital Signal Analysis: Sinusoid and Filtering problem

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I was wondering if someone could help me derive the answers for (ii) and (iii)? These are exam review problems, not homework, and **I have no idea how to solve them.** I have been trying to reference my textbook/look for help online but it has been very difficult for me to find examples online similar to this one, so I figured I would give this a shot. The answer I got for (i) was .25 seconds (from getting the frequency of each sinusoid and then finding the greatest factor to get the fundamental). Any help is extremely appreciated!
[image: exam problem #1]

Edit: I got these answers

$$b = \left[ \begin{array}{lllllllll}
1.7 & 0 & 0 & 3.5e^{-2.1j} & 0 & 0 & 7.9e^{0.8j} & 0 & 5.4e^{1.1j}
\end{array} \right]'$$

$$c = 512$$

But I am not sure why vector b has \$0\$'s in it, can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency components in \$x(t)\$ are :  DC, 12Hz, 24Hz and 32Hz.

(i) So the signal is going to be repeated at 4Hz. or \$T=0.25sec\$

(ii) You are taking the IFFT of b to get x. or, b will have non-zero values at zeroth harmonics (DC), 3rd harmonics (12Hz), 6th harmonics (24Hz) and at 8th harmonics (32Hz) of fundamental frequency (4Hz) all other positions will be occupied by zeroes. The non-zero values would be in form \$magnitude\times exp(phase)\$.  Hence the answer.

(iii) You are using an LPF with \$f_c = 15hz\$. Therefore output will contain frequency components less than 15Hz only. 
$$y(t) = 1.7 + 3.5cos(24\pi t - 2.1)$$